# Kendo UI treeview find the next node and previous node of the selected node

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a kenduo UI treeview, when I selected one node I want to get the next node and the previous node of this node so I can use InsertAfter and InsertBefore methods to move up or move down the node I selected.

anyone know how to do ? thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use jQuery [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) for getting the nodes. You can use:

```
var sel = treeview.select();
var next = $(sel).next();
var prev = $(sel).prev();
```

Where:

- `treeview` is the `treeview` object (i.e. `$("#grid").data("kendoTreeView")`)
- `sel` is current selected node,
- `next` is next node.
- and `prev` previous node.

If you need to get the item in the model you should use `treeview.dataItem` with `sel`, `next` or `prev` as argument.

Comment: hi OnaBai, thanks very much for your help, this is what I wanted.